Союз "но": однородный член или уточняющий оборот?
3дравствуйте, русские братья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, верны ли мои мысли насчёт постановки запятой в таком предложении: "Хлеб большой, но чёрствый, стоял на столе", заключающиеся в том, что "но чёрствый" является уточняющим оборотом и что без запятой после него предложение приобретает неоднозначность, т. о. она необходима?

Правильно:
Хлеб,  большой, но чёрствый, стоял на столе.
Это обособленный определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, поэтому он обособляется. В составе оборота два определения, связанные сочинительным союзом НО.
Это актуализация (подчеркивание) оборота, а уточняющим оборот будет при наличии определения в препозиции, например:
Праздничный хлеб, большой, но чёрствый, стоял на столе.

Благодарю. А ежели мы составим предложение так: "Большой хлеб, но чёрствый, стоял на столе"?

Стилистика нехороша, лучше так: Большой, но черствый хлеб стоял на столе. Здесь однородные определения, обособления нет.
